# Maskfield selected values

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine

I have a (int)maskfield that contains selected values of selectlist.
Documentation : [MaskField](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.MaskField.html)
I have a string array that corresponds to the entries of the maskfield.

After filling this maskfield I want to retrieve what options wehere selected in my array.
How can I do that with this int ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do it :

```
ArrayList maGroupNames; // This is my array of options (string)
int mCategory; // This is my maskfield's result

for (int i = 0; i < maGroupNames.Count; i++)
{
    int layer = 1 << i;
    if ((mCategory & layer) != 0)
    {
        //This group is selected
    }
}
```

Comment: After adding new item to `MaskField` options, that flag doesn't show correct number. How did you fix it ?